# I need to backup and then recover multiple files in different directorys with /bin/sh

Tags: copy, sed, awk, sh

As the title say. I need to be able to backup and then recover files.

To make the back up was pretty simple

```
 if [ "$bup" = "true" ]; then
     cp $file $file.bak
```

But to make the recovery.. was not as stright forward.

```
 elif [ "$rup" = "true" ]; then
     bak=`find /path/to/file/ | grep .bak`
     cp $bak ${bak/\.bak}
 fi
```

It works in bash but i need it to work in sh..

Comment: It's not necessary to use `grep` with `find`: `find /path/to/file -name "*.bak*"` or more likely `find /path/to/file -name "*.bak"`

Comment: Is it anything bad with it? That is how i use find normaly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash shell parameter expansion doesn't work in sh.  Try this:

```
elif [ "$rup" = "true" ]; then
   bak=`find /path/to/file/ | grep .bak`
   orig=`echo $bak | sed 's/\.bak$//'`
   cp $bak $orig
fi
```

Don't forget to add a loop around that find output if you intend to process multiple .bak files.

Answer (score 0):

Use substring processing instead of the regex variant:

```
orig=${bak%.bak}
```